# Where to find the Android icon to indicate there is more if you tap a list row?

Tags: android, listview, icons

Is there a system provided icon on Android to put in a tableView row to indicate that there is more if you select the row?

In IOS one would use a chevron 'accessory' style. On Android I've seen a triangle in a circle being used (e.g. In the Settings app). But to my surprise it is not available in android.R.drawable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, Android doesn't make these available to you via the resources, so you will have to copy them to your project from the SDK. You want `expander_ic_minimized` and `expander_ic_maximized`, which you can find inside the any of the sdk data folders  (`android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-N\data\res\drawable-hdpi`).